# How can I use jQuery on server-side javascript?

Tags: jquery, serverside-javascript

I want to use the ajax method in jQuery on a server-side javascript file, is there any way to include jquery.js into my javascript file?

Comment: Interesting. What platform are you using that makes use of server side javascript? node.js? (If you are not using node.js then there is no way to use javascript on the server side.)

Comment: I'm using a comet implementation and it uses javascript on server side.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this? The strength of jQuery is DOM traversal and operations, which doesn't really help in server-side stuff..

Comment: @Jane - way more information is needed.  What comet implementation, what exactly is the server software?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use jQuery as server side Javascript. I just found new JS#jQuery library for server side on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20use%20jquery%20for%20server%20side&oq=how%20to%20use%20jquery%20for%20serv&gs_l=hp.3.0.33i29.0.0.3.80.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.hEgC3XpeLZs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=12d58a39db1e986c&biw=1280&bih=906) search.

```
https://bitbucket.org/illume/ssjquery
```

How to use ssjQuery..?

Here the link: http://renesd.blogspot.in/2011/10/server-side-jquery-ssjquery.html